# report on multi tables is showing up duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have mulipule tables that im pulling from.  I am only interested in a few fields from each. When I run the report it goes off and gets what I need but has duplicates. I have tried many things (the latest being adding the Distinct select that helped a little.

here is the SQL I have setup

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CN_HEADER.CHD_CONS_REF

  ,CN_HEADER.CHD_SUPP_ACC

  ,CN_HEADER.CHD_SUPP_BRN

  ,STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_STOCK_CODE

  ,STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_STORE

  ,STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_CONSIGN_REF

  ,CN_STK_DTL_NUM.CSI_CONS_REF

  ,CN_STK_DTL_NUM.CSI_STOCK_CODE

  ,CN_STK_DTL_NUM.CSI_STORE_CODE

  ,CN_STK_DTL_NUM.CSI_INTERNAL_NO

  ,STK_MASTER.SK_STOCK_CODE

  ,PL_SUPPLIER.SU_ACC_CODE

  ,PL_SUPPLIER.SU_BRANCH

  ,PL_SUPPLIER.SU_SHORTNAME

  ,QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_CHECK_ID

  ,QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_CHECK_TYPE

  ,QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_CHECK_SEQ

  ,QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_QC_CODE

  ,QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_CHECK_ID

  ,QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_CONS_REF

  ,QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_SUPPLIER_ACC

  ,QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_SUPPLIER_BRN

  ,QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_STOCK_CODE

  ,QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_STORE_CODE

  ,QC2_RESULT_VALS.MQRV_CHECK_ID

  ,QC2_RESULT_VALS.MQRV_CHECK_SEQ

  ,QC2_RESULT_VALS.MQRV_CHECK_TYPE

  ,QC2_RESULT_VALS.MQRV_VAL_SEQ

  ,QC2_RESULT_VALS.MQRV_DATA_TEXT

FROM

  CN_HEADER

  INNER JOIN STK_STORE_WHSE

    ON CN_HEADER.CHD_CONS_REF = STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_CONSIGN_REF

  INNER JOIN QC2_RESULT_HDR

    ON CN_HEADER.CHD_CONS_REF = QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_CONS_REF

  INNER JOIN PL_SUPPLIER

    ON CN_HEADER.CHD_SUPP_ACC = PL_SUPPLIER.SU_ACC_CODE AND CN_HEADER.CHD_SUPP_BRN = 
PL_SUPPLIER.SU_BRANCH
  INNER JOIN CN_STK_DTL_NUM

    ON STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_STOCK_CODE = CN_STK_DTL_NUM.CSI_STOCK_CODE AND STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_STORE = 
CN_STK_DTL_NUM.CSI_STORE_CODE AND STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_CONSIGN_REF = CN_STK_DTL_NUM.CSI_CONS_REF

  INNER JOIN STK_MASTER

    ON STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_STOCK_CODE = STK_MASTER.SK_STOCK_CODE

  INNER JOIN QC2_RESULT_DTL

    ON QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_CHECK_ID = QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_CHECK_ID

  INNER JOIN QC2_RESULT_VALS

    ON QC2_RESULT_HDR.MQRH_CHECK_ID = QC2_RESULT_VALS.MQRV_CHECK_ID



WHERE

CN_HEADER.CHD_CONS_REF = @CHD_CONS_REF
AND 
QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_CHECK_SEQ = QC2_RESULT_VALS.MQRV_CHECK_SEQ
AND 
QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_QC_CODE LIKE N'KEY%'or QC2_RESULT_DTL.MQRD_QC_CODE LIKE N'HIGHRISK'
```

---

Comment: probably you are having some Cartesian joins, try to post a sample of your data

Comment: Mucio is most likely correct, with this many joins you are likely picking up rows from a table that you don't intend (maybe a status flag = 'y'?).  Take your results and identify one of the 'duplicate' rows by ID.  Change your select statement to select * from ... where id = 'id_you_selected' and give it a run.  Compare all columns, is it truely a duplicate record or is there a single difference in one of the columns?  There might be a small difference that the select * reveals that this script doesn't show...that will help you identify where the duplicates are originating.

Comment: Hi Here is an example of the duplicate records.

Comment: it wont let me post screen shots on here as I don't have enuff points

Comment: ok with this sql I put the chd_cons_ref as "9637" this brings back 73 results only looking at the fields I have requested on the SQL

after exporting to Excel to run filters and order each field I have found 11 unique records. the rest are duplicates

Comment: ok I have cut out some of the fields to clean this up

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
  CN_HEADER.CHD_CONS_REF
  ,CN_HEADER.CHD_SUPP_ACC

Comment: ,CN_HEADER.CHD_SUPP_BRN
  ,STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_STOCK_CODE
  ,STK_STORE_WHSE.STW_STORE

Comment: i cant post the new sql on here it stops me due to amount of txt

Comment: so all i have done is remove things like mqrv_store_code if store code is pulled in by another field. brought it down to just 13 fields now

Comment: CHD_CONS_REF, CHD_SUPP_ACC, CHD_SUPP_BRN, STW_STOCK_CODE, STW_STORE, CSI_INTERNAL_NO, SU_SHORTNAME, MQRD_CHECK_ID, MQRD_CHECK_TYPE, MQRD_CHECK_SEQ, MQRD_QC_CODE, MQRV_VAL_SEQ, MQRV_DATA_TEXT

Comment: MQRV_VAL_SEQ is a number seq. it gives a number ref to MQRV_DATA_TEXT so for Cons_REF 9637 

I have 2 stoke codes 12 and 13

stock code 12 has 6 MQRV_VAL_SEQ's numbers (0-5) 0 = Damaged 1 = scratch and so on. 

but code 13 has 7 MQRV_VAL_SEQ's and they are not in the same order e.g. 0 = scratched 1 = Blue and so on. 

this is ok so i would expect to see 11 records 1 set for 12 and 1 set for 13 but i see 12 for "12" and 14 for "13" it seems to double up on all stock codes unless there is only 1 stock code like in REF "9668" and it works ok and only brings back 1 of each

Comment: It looks like its merging the 2 together. I have created a report in SQL server report builder and split each page by stock code and it shows all the MQRV_DATA_TEXT on both pages instead of just on the page for that stock code

Comment: found the problem. one of the tables holds separate records for each search. I have removed the table and it works like a dream now